# Passando parametros de uma Activity para uma classe de cálculo

Tags: java, android

Gostaria que vocês me ajudassem em uma situação que estou fazendo no meu projeto, mas que de alguma forma o aplicativo para ao clicar no botão calcular.

Vou dar um exemplo simples para ter noção mais ou menos do que eu necessito. O usuário entrar com dois números em uma Activity de entrada de dados, esses números vão para uma classe (somente para calcular, sem Activity) e depois retornam para uma Activity de resultado.

Preciso que vocês me mostrem exatamente como faz essa transição, no que eu errei etc. Isso porque no meu projeto tenho muito mais variáveis e muito mais contas a serem realizadas, sendo que precisarei de duas classes de cálculos (pois os cálculos são distintos)

Desde já agradeço a atenção. Espero ter sido clara e ter dado um exemplo simples para solução.

**Activity de entrada de dados**

```
    public class Entrada_Dados extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener{

    //Declarando variáveis
        public EditText txt_numero1;
        public EditText txt_numero2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_entrada__dados);

    //Relacionando variáveis com objetos
        txt_numero1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_numero1);
        txt_numero2= EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_numero2);

    }

    public void onClick (View View) {

    //Transferindo parâmetros
        Intent it = new Intent(this, Calculo.class );

        it.putExtra("numero1", txt_numero1.getText().toString());
        it.putExtra("numero2", txt_numero2.getText().toString());

        startActivity(it);
        finish();
    }
}
```

**Classe de cálculo**

```
 public class Calculo extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Declarando variáveis
    public double numero1;
    public double numero2;
    public double resultado;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String txt_numero1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("numero1"); //Recuperar na string
        numero1=Double.parseDouble(txt_numero1); //Passando para double

        String txt_numero2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("numero2"); //Recuperar na string
        numero2=Double.parseDouble(txt_numero2); //Passando para double

        startActivity(new Intent(this, Resultado.class));

    }

public double calculo_soma(){

        return resultado = numero1 + numero2;

    }
```

**Activity de resultado**

```
  public class Resultado extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    public TextView txt_resultado;

        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_resultado);

        txt_resultado= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_resultado);

    }

    public void onClick (View v){

    //Chamando a classe
        Calculo Calculo = new Calculo ();

        double calculo_soma = Calculo.calculo_soma(); 
        String stg_resultado = Double.toString(calculo_soma);
        txt_resultado.setText(stg_resultado);

    }
}
```

**Perguntaram qual o erro que estava dando (lembrando que o exemplo que dei aqui não é o do meu projeto, mas a figura que vou acrescentar é do app que estou fazendo **
[image: Erro]

Comment: Qual é o erro apresentado no *logcat*?

Comment: Coloquei a imagem de erro no post. Não sei interpretar esses erros ainda :( Peço desculpas.

Comment: Você tem um botão em que no xml está declarado um `onClick` que não tem o respectivo método na Activity.

Comment: Cara... é estranho porque nesse mesmo botão tem um código em que ele verifica se os EditText's estão vazios, e isso funciona. Agora, quando todos os EditText estão preenchidos, ele deveria levar as informações para uma classe de cálculo e depois abrir uma Activity com as respostas. Ai ele não faz.

Comment: Pode ser que o meu raciocínio de transferência de parâmetros esteja incoerente. Ai deduzi que pode ser que seja isso que esteja travando o app.

Comment: E um outro fato interessante que eu percebo é que nos botões que tem no projeto, quando eu vou ao evento OnClick, nas propriedades, para selecionar qual public void o botão tem que atuar, sempre aparecem dois eventos iguais. Tipo, eu clico no OnClick e aparece duas opções, por exemplo: "OnClick (Resultado)" e "OnClick (Resultado)". Quando isso ocorre eu seleciono o segundo, porque é o que funciona, o primeiro não funciona rsrsrs

Comment: Parece o erro que acontece comigo quando eu declaro no xml um método mais esqueço de colocar no código java

Comment: Mas no meu caso está declarado em ambos, código java e xml.

Comment: Gente, meu raciocínio acima está correto? rsrsrs

Comment: Em vez de criar classes para os cálculos, porque você não cria métodos e mantem tudo numa mesma activity? Ou cria uma atividade para cada tipo de calculo, mas mantem os cálculos atrelados a atividade correspondente. Muito mais fácil passar os dados e manter um código coeso.